# Intertwined problems with Django Time fields force hacks to edit/display time

Tags: django

Django 2

There's alot of info here.  I'll try to summarise the essence of the issues.

Background fact: Setting a default for a Time field requires that a datetime.time be set in the model reference: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6754

There are two problems here that are related.

**Problem 1: the data type of the time field changes**

First problem is that the initial GET of the Django page below returns a time field with a data type of `<class 'datetime.time'>`.  This is fine and expected.

BUT If you submit that form via POST, *and there is a field validation error*, then ***the data type of the Time field CHANGES to a string***. Have a look at the server log at the bottom of this question to see.  As a consequence, the format of the data changes too - note that the seconds are dropped.  This can also be seen in the server log below.

This leads to problem 2:

**Problem 2: Django's time formatting tag returns None when there are no seconds on the data passed into it.**

In the HTML template below you can see the line containing:

```
time:'H:i'
```

This is a formatting tag, which accepts a time and it should output time in hh:mm format.  It works if the input is of the form 18:00:00.  It returns None if the input is of form 18:00

**The user experience of this:**

So what happens is that the user loads the form initially via GET and the default time is displayed OK in HH:MM format. The user fills in some fields and submits, and if there is a validation error, then the page is displayed again, with validation error messages, BUT now the time has disappeared because it changed data type to string, which dropped the seconds, and now no time gets displayed because the Django template time filter tag returns None if its input has no seconds.

**Question 1:**
How can I fix this without resorting to a hack of forcing the time field through an additional field that I convert to a string.  This works but it's just a hack to get around the problems above.

**Question 2:**
Why does the type of the time field change from datetime.time to string when it is POSTed to the server after the initial GET form load?

**Question 3:**
Why does the Django template time tag transformation return None when its input does not contain seconds?

Django HTML template:

```
<form action="{% url 'main:testtime' %}" method="post">

    <br/><br/>
    Event title<br/>
    {% if form.title.errors %}
        {% for error in form.title.errors %}
            <div class="form-error">{{ error|escape }}</div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
    <input type="text"
           name="title"
           id="id_title"
    >

    <br/><br/>
    Event time<br/>
    {{ form.time.value|time:'H:i' }}<br/>
    {{ form.time.value }}<br/>
    <input
            type="time"
            name="time"
            required
            step="60"
            id="id_time"
            value="{{ form.time.value|time:'H:i' }}"
    >

    <br/><br/>
    {% csrf_token %}

    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Django form:

```
class TestForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Event

        fields = [
            'date',
            'time',
            'title',
        ]

    def clean_title(self):
        raise forms.ValidationError('This forces a valdation error')
```

Django model (a bunch of irrelevant fields removed)

```
class Event(models.Model):
    @staticmethod
    def default_datetime():
        return datetime.time(18, 00, 00)

    date = models.DateField(blank=False, null=False)
    time = models.TimeField(default=default_datetime.__func__, blank=False, null=False)
    title = models.TextField()
```

Relevant line from urls.py

```
path('testtime/', views.testtime, name='testtime'),
```

Relevant function from views.py

```
@require_http_methods(['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def testtime(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestForm(request.POST)
        print("POST HANDLE NEW EVENT")

    elif request.method == 'GET':
        form = TestForm()
        print("GET NEW EVENT")

    print("type of form['time'].value() is:")
    print(type(form['time'].value()))
    print("value of form['time'].value() is:")
    print(form['time'].value())

    return render(request, 'main/testtime.html', {
        'form': form,
    })
```

server log:

```
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: GET NEW EVENT
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: type of form['time'].value() is:
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: <class 'datetime.time'>
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: value of form['time'].value() is:
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: 18:00:00
Jan 22 21:39:22 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: [pid: 14647|app: 0|req: 1/5] xx.xx.102.186 () {44 vars in 1026 bytes} [Tue Jan 22 21:39:22 2019] GET /testtime/ => generated 580 bytes in 108 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (2 switches on core 0)



Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: POST HANDLE NEW EVENT
Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: type of form['time'].value() is:
Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: <class 'str'>
Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: value of form['time'].value() is:
Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: 20:03
Jan 22 21:39:37 ip-10-0-1-251 uwsgi[14637]: [pid: 14645|app: 0|req: 3/6] xx.xx.102.186 () {54 vars in 1263 bytes} [Tue Jan 22 21:39:37 2019] POST /testtime/ => generated 658 bytes in 8 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 293 bytes (2 switches on core 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Question 1: How can I fix this without resorting to a hack of forcing
>   the time field through an additional field that I convert to a string.
>   This works but it's just a hack to get around the problems above.

You should use the form fields in the templates to get around this. Rather than

```
<input
        type="time"
        name="time"
        required
        step="60"
        id="id_time"
        value="{{ form.time.value|time:'H:i' }}"
>
```

Use:

```
 {{ form.time }}
```

If you need to modify the attributes, you can do so via in the form class definition.

> Question 2: Why does the type of the time field change from
>   datetime.time to string when it is POSTed to the server after the
>   initial GET form load?

On the GET flow, value is set to the default which is a python time object. For the POST flow, value is set to the value from `request.POST` which comes in as a string. If you were to run `.is_valid()` then check `form.cleaned_data['time']` it would be an instance of `datetime.time`.

> Question 3: Why does the Django template time tag transformation
>   return None when its input does not contain seconds?

(I think) This isn't because it doesn't have any seconds, but because the value it's being applied to is a string. If you use `cleaned_data` it would render properly. However, that's going to mean you're going to need a if/else to handle when it's a GET/POST or a check on the form to see if `cleaned_data` is set yet.

Comment: So am I correct in understanding that the initial data type is datetime.time when the value first comes out of the model, that it is string following the POST, and presumably it is converted back to being a time to be stored into the Postgres database via the model and thus when loaded again later will be a datetime.time?

Comment: That sounds pretty close, but I'd suggest reading some of the docs to verify. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/api/#accessing-clean-data